# How to create a table that interact with database in real time

Tags: database, plugin-contact-form-7

I started a WordPress project recently which am using plugin like mycred and contact form 7.

i have the following field input in contact form 7

- name
- email
- address
- Card
- no Picture

I will be saving this field into my database with help of submission plugin

But i would like to create a table in my frontend page probably HTML and JavaScript that will display only what the current login user has submitted alone.

Example of the table

Name | Email | card number | amount to be paid out | button Add to account

1) The card number is 20 digit I would want the table to only show 5 digit and the rest with ***********

2) I want to had an hidden field named "amount to be paid out" which only me can edit at the backend whenever  a user submit that form - i edit the hidden field with an amount, i want the user to be able to add the amount i specify to his mycred account balance with the "ADD To Account" bottom and if specify to 0 the button should be disable

Please can someone help me out and please specify appropriate place to paste the code?

Comment: How can someone know how the data is stored in database?? Is there is custom table for it submission plugin or any other plugin?

Comment: What about this is "real time"?

Answer (score 0):

I would use [Post My Contact Form](https://wordpress.org/plugins/post-my-contact-form-7/) plugin extension.   You can map your form to a custom post or an existing post type, and map individual form fields to custom post fields.

Each form submissions are stored as a post in your dashboard and the author of the submission is set to the logged in user.  Therefore when you display your form, you can display a table (above or below) with the previously submitted posts for that user.  You'll need to get all the posts for that author in your page template using a [custom query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) like,

```
// The Query
$user = wp_get_current_user();
$args = array(
  'post_type'=> 'my-form-post' //the custom post type to which you mapped your form.
  'post_author' => $user->ID,
);
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

// The Loop
if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
    //build your table here....
    echo '<ul>';
    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
        $the_query->the_post();
        echo '<li>' . get_the_title() . '</li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';
    /* Restore original Post Data */
    wp_reset_postdata();
} else {
    // no posts found
}
```